# Glow effect in Phaser3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Does anybody know how to add a simple glow effect to a sprite in Phaser3?  I've seen some examples in Phaser2, but haven't been able to find anything for Phaser3.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only Phaser 2 glow effect I could find was that at https://codepen.io/Samid737/pen/ZyPvya, which added a time component to https://gist.github.com/MatthewBarker/032c325ef8577c6d0188. The relevant bit is the fragment:

```
this.fragmentSrc = [
    'precision lowp float;',
    'varying vec2 vTextureCoord;',
    'varying vec4 vColor;',
    'uniform sampler2D uSampler;',
    'uniform float alpha;',
    'uniform float time;',
    'void main() {',
        'vec4 sum = vec4(0);',
        'vec2 texcoord = vTextureCoord;',
        'for(int xx = -4; xx <= 4; xx++) {',
            'for(int yy = -4; yy <= 4; yy++) {',
                'float dist = sqrt(float(xx*xx) + float(yy*yy));',
                'float factor = 0.0;',
                'if (dist == 0.0) {',
                    'factor = 2.0;',
                '} else {',
                    'factor = 2.0/abs(float(dist));',
                '}',
                'sum += texture2D(uSampler, texcoord + vec2(xx, yy) * 0.002) * (abs(sin(time))+0.06);',
            '}',
        '}',
        'gl_FragColor = sum * 0.025 + texture2D(uSampler, texcoord)*alpha;',
    '}'
];
```

Phaser 3 just requires a few of these be updated. Using the official [custom pipeline labs example](http://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src%5Crenderer%5CCustom%20Pipeline.js):

```
var CustomPipeline = new Phaser.Class({
    Extends: Phaser.Renderer.WebGL.Pipelines.TextureTintPipeline,
    initialize:
    function CustomPipeline (game)
    {
    Phaser.Renderer.WebGL.Pipelines.TextureTintPipeline.call(this, {
            game: game,
            renderer: game.renderer,
            fragShader: [
                'precision lowp float;',
                'varying vec2 outTexCoord;',
                'varying vec4 outTint;',
                'uniform sampler2D uMainSampler;',
                'uniform float alpha;',
                'uniform float time;',
                'void main() {',
                    'vec4 sum = vec4(0);',
                    'vec2 texcoord = outTexCoord;',
                    'for(int xx = -4; xx <= 4; xx++) {',
                        'for(int yy = -4; yy <= 4; yy++) {',
                            'float dist = sqrt(float(xx*xx) + float(yy*yy));',
                            'float factor = 0.0;',
                            'if (dist == 0.0) {',
                                'factor = 2.0;',
                            '} else {',
                                'factor = 2.0/abs(float(dist));',
                            '}',
                            'sum += texture2D(uMainSampler, texcoord + vec2(xx, yy) * 0.002) * (abs(sin(time))+0.06);',
                        '}',
                    '}',
                    'gl_FragColor = sum * 0.025 + texture2D(uMainSampler, texcoord)*alpha;',
                '}'
            ].join('\n')
        });
    } 
});
```

Then you can load this in and assign it to sprites:

```
function preload() {
    this.load.image('logo', 'assets/Phaser-Logo-Small.png');
    this.load.image('dude', 'assets/phaser-dude.png');

    customPipeline = game.renderer.addPipeline('Custom', new CustomPipeline(game));
    customPipeline.setFloat1('alpha', 1.0);
}

function create() {

    this.add.sprite(500, 300, 'logo').setPipeline('Custom');
    this.add.sprite(50, 50, 'dude').setPipeline('Custom');
}

var time = 0.0;

function update()
{
    customPipeline.setFloat1('time', time);
    time += 0.05;
}
```

Comment: James, thanks so much for taking the time to respond!  I just played around with this a bit, and it does seem like I can get this to work for me.  Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. :)

Comment: Thank you for the Phaser 3 example!

Comment: The provided `CustomPipeline` doesn't seem to work anymore in today's Phaser 3. (I tried it with the example in the lab and it just darkens the sprites)

Comment: @Telokis are you sure you updated all the bits? If you're using the labs example as your base, you need to update the `CustomPipeline` creation, `preload()`, and `update()`. I was just able to get a bouncing glow effect.

Comment: @JamesSkemp Ok it works, thanks! I had forgotten about the functions.

Comment: For those who uses Phaser 3.50.0 or later, `TextureTintPipeline` is called `MultiPipeline`. [Ref](https://js.libhunt.com/phaser-changelog/3.50.0-beta.4)

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer and add a new section at the bottom with your comment @Tura :)

Comment: In fact, MultiPipeline takes uMainSampler as an array of samplers so the code should be changed a little bit. I'll edit the answer to reflect new changes soon :)